# Call php in system.xml

Tags: magento2

I want to call a `php` file containing first name in `system.xml`.

I know that it can be done by using `source_model` and using `class class_name implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface`

Is there any other way to do so without using `\Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface`

Comment: This question needs clarification